# Gitlab CI CD: keeping docker env files

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I need to store somewhere .env files for docker-compose. One approach is to store their contents in masked variables in gitlab CI/CD but it seems not secure for me as hacking quite a lot of apps would only take someone to crack a gitlab account.

I would like to store .env files in a directory on server and copy them to new pulled repository path in the first job of CI/CD. I tried artifacts for that, but they are uploaded to gitlab and can be viewed there and I didn't manage to find them in the later jobs (ls in after_script didn't show them).

How could I copy .env files into all jobs and not upload them on gitlab?

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker compose --version

copy_env_files:
  script:
    - cp /home/myuser/myapp/env.* .
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - env.*

build_image:
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - env.*

collect_static_files:
  script:
    - docker-compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - env.*

migrate_database:
  script:
    - docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate --no-input
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - env.*

after_script:
  - docker container ls
  - pwd
  - ls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have added "cp /home/myuser/myapp/env.* ." into before_script, not separate it as a job.

I also fixed my errors with django --no-input (by adding -T to docker exec) which occured after docker was successfully builded.

```
before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker compose --version
  - cp /home/myuser/myproject/env.* .

build_image:
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"

collect_static_files:
  script:
    - docker-compose exec -T web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"

migrate_database:
  script:
    - docker-compose exec -T web python manage.py migrate --no-input
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"

after_script:
  - docker container ls
```

Answer (score 2):

> How could I copy .env files into all jobs and not upload them on gitlab?

By integrating your gitlab-ci job to an external vault, where sensitive data would securely reside.

For instance: "[Authenticating and reading secrets with HashiCorp Vault](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/)", but it is for GitLab premium only.

You still can [use external secrets in CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/)

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/img/gitlab_vault_workflow_v13_4.png]

> - Configure your vault and secrets.
> - Generate your JWT and provide it to your CI job.
> - Runner contacts HashiCorp Vault and authenticates using the JWT.
> - HashiCorp Vault verifies the JWT.
> - HashiCorp Vault checks the bounded claims and attaches policies.
> - HashiCorp Vault returns the token.
> - Runner reads secrets from the HashiCorp Vault.

Comment: Why do this when I have secret data securely stored on the server? I just want to copy it from a folder with a constant name to a github runner newly created folder, and as I mentioned, artifacts didn't help me

Comment: Sorry, I missed the securely stored part. I am used, as a best practice, to store secrets on an external dedicated vault referential.